# Swift TableView cell play button click and other cell button need to reset

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I am trying to listing `audio` files into `TableView` with custom `cell`. Here, each cell having single `button` (for `play/pause` audio). My problem is if I click play button within first cell or any cell other cell selected button need to `reset` (I mean first cell button click `play` to `pause` other or previous selected `cell` need to rest pause to normal).

My Current Output screen

[image: playlist]

Below code I am using, provide some idea’s

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: InviteCell = inviteTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomOneCell

    // here some code missing
    cell.btnCheck.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnCheck.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnCheck(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

return cell
}

@objc func btnCheck(_ sender: UIButton) {

        // Here I need to change Image and how to Implement my question
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: NSIndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0) as IndexPath) as! CustomOneCell

        /*if selectIndex != -1 && selectIndex != sender.tag
        {
            let bt:UIButton = self.view.viewWithTag(selectIndex) as! UIButton
            if bt.isSelected == true
            {
                bt.isSelected = false
                cell.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)
            }
        }*/

        if sender.isSelected == false
        {
            sender.isSelected = true
            selectIndex = sender.tag
            cell.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"pause.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        } else {
            sender.isSelected = false
            selectIndex = sender.tag
            cell.playButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: set isSelected in your custom cell class

Comment: `override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            
            if isSelected {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
                
            } else {
                backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Please provide sample code. it will help lots of people and for me also. Thanks @canister_exister

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your View Controller you have array of items I suppose. This item should have some property which represents if item isPlaying or not. For example

```
var isPlaying: Bool = // true if playing, false if not
```

If you have just array of strings you have to create custom class/struct

```
struct Audio {
    var title: String = ""
    var isPlaying: Bool = false
}
```

Now in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: InviteCell = inviteTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomOneCell

    let item = yourItemArray[indexPath.row]
    let image = item.isPlaying ? UIImage(named:"pause.png") : UIImage(named:"play.png")
    cell.playButton.setImage(image, for: UIControlState.normal)
    cell.btnCheck.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.btnCheck.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.btnCheck(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    return cell
}
```

And in action for your button just change value of item with index same as

```
@objc func btnCheck(_ sender: UIButton) {
    for item in yourItemArray {
        item.isPlaying = false
    }
    yourItemArray[sender.tag].isPlaying = !yourItemArray[sender.tag].isPlaying
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: hi @Robert Dresler my problem is not changing cell button image. My problem is I need to restrict if any cell button pause other cell button need to reset play. At a time user need to do one play. See above my output image multiple pause allowing but usually one play other all normal.

Comment: @pastelsdev okay, try edited answer with foreach loop in btnCheck action

Comment: Value of type 'String' has no member 'isPlaying' at line Value of type 'String' has no member 'isPlaying' @Robert Dresler

Comment: Yes, this is because your item is just string, you have to create custom class with two properties, one title and second isPlaying

Comment: it's better to be a class plus you don't flip the current state you always make it to play here **yourItemArray[sender.tag].isPlaying = true**

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your `CustomOneCell`

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    playButton.setImage(UIImage(named: selected ? "pause.png" : "play.png"), for:.normal)
}
```

And just select your cell in `btnCheck(_ sender: UIButton)`

```
func btnCheck(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    guard !cell.isSelected else { return } // return if cell is already selected

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.selectRow(at: [indexPath], animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```